# Using the position function inside a script tag in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is the complete code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*/hundreds/hundred">
<div class="page_spacer" />
<div class="page_section" style="{./style}">
<h2><xsl:value-of select="./label"/></h2>
<div id="graphDiv{position()}"></div>
<script>
var ctx = createCanvas("graphDiv{position()}");
var graph = new BarGraph(ctx);
graph.maxValue = 30;
graph.margin = 2;
graph.colors = ["#49a0d8", "#d353a0", "#ffc527", "#df4c27"];
graph.xAxisLabelArr = ["North", "East", "West", "South"];
setInterval(function () {
    graph.update([Math.random() * 30, Math.random() * 30, Math.random() * 30, Math.random() * 30]);
}, 1000);   
</script>
<xsl:value-of select="./descriptiontext" />
<button onclick="javascript:window.location.href='{./viewalllink}'"><xsl:value-of select="./viewalllabel" /></button>
<br/>
<xsl:for-each select="./contendors/contendor">
    <a href="/location/{./locid}" ><img class="locationthumb" src="/act/locationthumb/{./locid}"/></a>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

What I'm looking to accomplish is the following:

```
<div id="graphDiv{position()}"></div>
<script>
var ctx = createCanvas("graphDiv{position()}");
```

If you look, in my XSLT i assign the `div` to `graphDiv1` if its in the first position. In my script i call the `createCanvas function`. Unfortunately I need to pass the value `graphDiv1` to the `createCanvas function`.

So, I need to put the `position` into the `script` that calls `createCanvas`.

I'm sure I'm doing something incorrect, this is only my second day using XSLT.

here is my `XML`:

```
 <hundreds>
    <hundred>
        <style>test</style>
        <label>label</label>
        <descriptiontext>something description</descriptiontext>
        <viewalllink>viewurl</viewalllink>
        <viewalllabel>viewurl</viewalllabel>
        <contendors>
             <contendor>
                 <locid>810</locid>
             </contendor>
        <contendors>
     </hundred>
 </hundreds>
```

Comment: can u pls provide ur source xml?

Answer (score 0):

This link should help you:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tiphtml/

However instead of

```
<xsl:value-of select="value"/>
```

you need to do:

```
<xsl:value-of select ="position()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the preceding `div` element, you are doing this (which is good):

```
 <div id="graphDiv{position()}"></div>
```

The curly braces are known as [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates), and mean the expression inside them gets evaluated to output the result. As their name suggests, this is only valid in attribute values, not in plain text nodes. In the case of the text nodes, you can use `xsl:value-of`

```
    <script>
    var ctx = createCanvas("graphDiv<xsl:value-of select="position()" />");
    var graph = new BarGraph(ctx);
```

It may look "odd" at first sight, but remember that XSLT has no understanding of javascript. It just a piece of text as far as XSLT is concerned. You are just outputting an element with the name of `script` which has a text node as a child, and are including the value of `position()` as part of that text.